# Setting scroll position using Iscroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I have a cool function set up like this with iscroll,

```
var iscroll = {....
  main: {...
     init: function() {...
     page_iscroll = new iScroll(...) {}
```

the question is how do i setup an initial y scroll position for the iscroll object, when it's initialized?

Comment: nevermind, i got it.  just gotta say

Comment: page_iscroll.scrollTo(x,y);

Answer (score 2):

there it is, the answer

page_iscroll.scrollTo(x,y);